# Currency Conversion function in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I created a scalar function shown below. Now I have a requirement to alter this function, provide an optional parameter to this function and it should return a table set. I tried using case statement and if exists, but it's not returning me the desired result set.

Here are the two result sets:

**A. Without optional parameter**

```
SELECT fnPay(@Id,  @Id1,  @Id2, @Id3 , @Id4)
```

result set:

```
Result
-------
123.00
```

**B. Optional parameter specified.**

```
SELECT fnPay fnPay(@Id,  @Id1,  @Id2, @Id3 , @Id4, 1)
```

Result set:

```
Col1 Col2 Col3
--------------
ABC  XYZ  KLM
```

Can someone please help me with this?

```
CREATE FUNCTION fnPay
(@Id1 DATETIME ,
 @Id2 NVARCHAR(5),
 @Id3 NVARCHAR(5),
 @Id4 NUMERIC(8,4)
)
RETURNS NUMERIC(8, 4)
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @Result NUMERIC(8,4);

    SET @Result = (SELECT t1.Description 
                   FROM tbl1 t1
                   JOIN tbl2 t2 ON t2.id = t1.id 
                   JOIN tbl3 t3 ON t3.id = t2.id
                   WHERE t1.id = 1 
                     AND t2.id = 2
                     AND .......)

    RETURN @Result 
END
```

Comment: I don't completely understand your requirement. A function is either scalar valued or table valued

Comment: You should convert this to an inline table valued function. It will not only out perform the scalar function but also you can have it return multiple columns.

Comment: Hi Lamak, even I was confused with the requirement. When I got this requirement I was asked to create a function giving two result sets
i) When optional parameter is not specified then it should return only one column.
ii) When optional parameter is specified then it should return more than one column

Comment: I sure hope your parameters have better names in the real code.

Comment: @newbee That's clearly not enough information for us to answer. You want a function that return 2 results set, what does it mean?, what results?

Comment: Yes, I had given better names in the code. And I tried creating an Inline table Valued function using a case statement, but it's throwing me errors.

Comment: @Lamak I edited my question. Initially I created a Scalar Valued Function, but as requirement has been changed I tried created an Inline Valued Table Function to achieve the desired result set using case statement and If exists, but they didn't seem to work.

Comment: A table valued function returns a table with a fixed number of columns. You can't change the number of columns depending on a parameter

Comment: So I have to write two functions as per my requirement?
i) Scalar function: which returns one column as Output
ii) Inline Function: Which returns more than one column as Output

Comment: Well, a scalar function is just that, a scalar, so it doesn't have columns. But, yeah, your idea seems to be correct

Comment: I would suggest not using a scalar function if at all possible. I realize you probably need two functions here but I would turn the original scalar into an itvf as well.